# JavaScript onClick Parameter says variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, onclick

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: PAGEHTML is not defined
```

My Object is defined in my JS why does this return an error? I have other onclicks that I've passed the object name through.

HTML

```
<button id="addLocation" onclick="insertBefore(PAGEHTML.uarAddLocation, addLocation)">+ Add Location</button>
```

JS OBJECT

```
var PAGEHTML = {
    uarAddLocation: `<label for="amountUnusual">Amount of Unusual Activity</label>
        <input id="amountUnusual" class="number" />
        <div class="fourtyFiveWidth inlineBlock">
            <label for="fromDate">Unusual Activity Start Date</label>
            <input id="fromDate" class="datepicker number" />
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left: calc(10% - 4px)" class="fourtyFiveWidth inlineBlock">
            <label for="toDate">Unusual Activity End Date</label>
            <input id="toDate" class="datepicker number" />
        </div>
        <label for="AULocation">Unusual Activity Location</label>
        <input id="AULocation" />`;
};
```

JS FUNC

```
function insertBefore(selector, html){
  console.log("selector: "+selector);
  $(html).insertBefore("#"+selector);
};
```

Comment: Is PAGEHTML a global variable? (If would have to be to be accessible from an inline event handler.)

Comment: You are passing `PAGEHTML.uarLocation` to your function but your object is called `PAGEHTML.uarAddLocation`

Comment: @JmJ I see, I have made the change and still receive the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your onclick:

```
onclick="insertBefore(PAGEHTML.uarLocation, addLocation)"
```

- You're passing the HTML (`PAGEHTML.uarAddLocation`) as the `selector`
- `addLocation` has to be wrapped with quotes
- `PAGEHTML.uarLocation` doesn't exist, but `PAGEHTML.uarAddLocation` does
- Your function has to have a different name, it causes issues with native [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

So it should be like this:

```
onclick="insertBefor('addLocation', PAGEHTML.uarAddLocation)"
```

Here's a working snippet:

```js
var PAGEHTML = {
    uarAddLocation: `<label for="amountUnusual">Amount of Unusual Activity</label>
        <input id="amountUnusual" class="number" />
        <div class="fourtyFiveWidth inlineBlock">
            <label for="fromDate">Unusual Activity Start Date</label>
            <input id="fromDate" class="datepicker number" />
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left: calc(10% - 4px)" class="fourtyFiveWidth inlineBlock">
            <label for="toDate">Unusual Activity End Date</label>
            <input id="toDate" class="datepicker number" />
        </div>
        <label for="AULocation">Unusual Activity Location</label>
        <input id="AULocation" />`
};

function insertBefor(selector, html){
  console.log("selector: " + selector);
  $(html).insertBefore("#"+selector);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addLocation" onclick="insertBefor('addLocation', PAGEHTML.uarAddLocation)">+ Add Location</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe wrap the second parameter in quotes?

```
<button id="addLocation" onclick="insertBefore(PAGEHTML.uarLocation, 'addLocation')">+ Add Location</button>
```

EDIT:

Like JmJ noted, the key is also wrong. Should be "uarAddLocation":

```
<button id="addLocation" onclick="insertBefore(PAGEHTML.uarAddLocation, 'addLocation')">+ Add Location</button>
```

Comment: That may be necessary, and from the definition of insertBefore() I think the arguments are the wrong way around, but it doesn't explain why there would be a reference error that explicitly mentions PAGEHTML.

Comment: Right... I would want to see a complete code. Also updated my answer according to JmJ's observation...

Comment: why _"Maybe wrap the second parameter in quotes"_? the second parameter is used as a selector or a jquery wrapper: `$(html)`. `<addLocation></addLocation>` doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the errors mentioned by others

1. *"You are passing `PAGEHTML.uarLocation` to your function but your object is called `PAGEHTML.uarAddLocation`"*
2. *"Maybe wrap the second parameter in quotes?"*

Note this

3. `insertBefore` is a built-in javascript method, so you cannot use that name for your function.

```js
var PAGEHTML = {

uarAddLocation: `<label for="amountUnusual">Amount of Unusual Activity</label>
            <input id="amountUnusual" class="number" />
            <div class="fourtyFiveWidth inlineBlock">
                <label for="fromDate">Unusual Activity Start Date</label>
                <input id="fromDate" class="datepicker number" />
            </div>
            <div style="margin-left: calc(10% - 4px)" class="fourtyFiveWidth inlineBlock">
                <label for="toDate">Unusual Activity End Date</label>
                <input id="toDate" class="datepicker number" />
            </div>
            <label for="AULocation">Unusual Activity Location</label>
            <input id="AULocation" />`

};

function insertBefor(selector, html){
  alert(selector);
  $(html).insertBefore("#"+selector);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addLocation" onclick="insertBefor(PAGEHTML.uarAddLocation, 'addLocation')">+ Add Location</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you must be referencing the object before it gets created. Even if you load the JavaScript at the top of your HTML file, if the HTML executes first this will occur. My suggestion is naming the HTML element inside the javacript block or file after the object is created, or create the HTML block there too.